# sqlite3 - the philosophy behind sqlite design for this scenario

Tags: sqlite

suppose we have a file with just one table named `TableA` and this table has just one column named `Text`; 
let say we populate our `TableA` with 3,000,000 of strings like these(**each line a record**):

```
Many of our patients are incontinent.
Many of our patients are severely disturbed.
Many of our patients need help with dressing.
```

if I save the file at this level it'll be: **~326 MB**

now let say we want to increase the speed of our queries and therefore we set our `Text` column as the PrimaryKey(or create index on it);

if I save the file at this level it'll be: **~700 MB**

our query:

```
SELECT Text FROM "TableA" where Text like '% home %'
```

for the table without index: **~5.545s**

for the indexed table: **~2.231s**

As far as I know when we create index on a column or set a column to be our PrimaryKey then sqlite engine doesn't need to refer to table itself(if no other column was requested in query) and it uses the index for query and hence the speed of query execution increases;

My question is in the scenario above which we have just one column and set that column to be the PrimaryKey too, then why sqlite holds some kind of unnecessary data?(at least it seems unnecessary!)(in this case **~326 MB**) why not just keeping the index\PrimaryKey data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQLite, table rows are stored in the order of the internal [rowid column](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid).
Therefore, indexes must be stored separately.

In SQLite 3.8.2 or later, you can create a [WITHOUT ROWID](http://www.sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html) table which is stored in order of its primary key values.